# Hanging bash loop script?

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop

```
varrr=0

while read line
do
    if [ $line -gt 500 -a $line -le 600 ]; then    # for lines 501-600
        echo $line >> 'file_out_${varrr}.ubi'
    fi
done << 'file_in_${varrr}.ubi'
```

`file_in_${varrr}.ubi` is a text file with around 1000 lines. I want to print lines 501-600 to new file.

Running this code leaves my Ubuntu terminal with a `>` symbol on a new line, as if I need to type another command to finish the loop. I can' figure out what is wrong with this loop though. Seems like it's complete. See any mistakes I've made? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm only going to answer your specific question: it's because you used a heredoc `<<` symbol, instead of a redirection `<`. Your last line should read:

```
done < 'file_in_${varrr}.ubi'
```

(observe the *single* `<`).

But then you'll realize that you have some quoting problems. So, your last line should read:

```
done < "file_in_${varrr}.ubi"
```

(observe the *double quotes* `"`).

Similarly, watch out your quotings in line 6. You should have this instead:

```
echo "$line" >> "file_out_${varrr}.ubi"
```

(*double quotes* `"` for `file_out_${varrr}.ubi`).

But then, this will not behave as you expect... Maybe this will do:

```
varrr=0
linenb=0
while IFS= read -r line; do
    ((++linenb))
    if ((linenb>500 && linenb<=600)); then    # for lines 501-600
        echo "$line" >> "file_out_${varrr}.ubi"
    fi
done < "file_in_${varrr}.ubi"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, yeah I needed a counter, as well as the quotation marks you pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to print lines from 501 to 600, why don't you use the following?

```
awk 'NR>=501 && NR<=600' file_in > file_out
```

`awk 'NR==n' myfile` prints the line `n` of the file `myfile`. Then, you can use ranges as I writted above.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I ended up using awk for this :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use sed. It's the simplest tool for it and is cleaner and faster than a `while` loop with tests.

```
varrr=0
sed -n 501,600p "file_in_${varrr}.ubi" >> "file_out_${varrr}.ubi"
```

Or

```
varrr=0
sed -n 501,600p "file_in_${varrr}.ubi" > "file_out_${varrr}.ubi"
```

If you want to override existing data.

The mistake in your loop by the way is because you're not using a counter and comparing your line number by the line itself instead.

```
varrr=0
counter=0
while read line; do
    (( ++counter ))
    [[ counter -gt 500 && counter -le 600 ]] && echo "$line"
done < "file_in_${varrr}.ubi" > "file_out_${varrr}.ubi"
```

Noticeably you need to use `<` for input not `<<` and place your variables around double quotes not single quotes.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to bash and you helped me understand I need a counter. Totally needed. But I'll look into using sed or awk instead.